# ExecuteNonQuery hangs in a new environment

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, iis, odbc

I have a webapp in asp.net mvc with a mysql db linked through ODBC driver.

Everything was working well in the old environment but now I have to move on a new server (new OS, new IIS, new mySql, new ODBC drivers).

It happens that in some part of the code the call to ExecuteNonQuery hangs.
In some other part it works.

The application is exactly the same as in old enviroment.
What I have changed is only the driver version in the connection string from

```
DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};
```

to

```
DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver};
```

The transaction should be very fast like update a row in a table of 200 rows.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the cause of the issue.

I just know the only way to fix it is to use

`DIM DR as ODBCDataReader = MyCommand.ExecuteReader`

Just don't read anything from the DataReader resource and everything will continue as expected.

The only way I have found to eliminate that random error. :/